# Why private class methods are not allowed in ruby classes?

Tags: ruby, oop

I came across this error while in development.

```rb
class ABC

  def self.method_1
    method_2
    p "method_1"
  end

  private

  def method_2
    p "method_2"
  end
end

ABC.method_1  # `method_1': undefined local variable or method `method_2' for ABC:Class (NameError)
```

But if I do it like this, then it works

```
  def self.method_1
    method_2
    p "method_1"
  end

  def self.method_2
    p "method_2"
  end

  private_class_method :method_2
end

ABC.method_1
```

Please help me in understanding this.

Comment: Your problem isn’t about public vs. private – it’s about instance method vs. class method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Jorg's answer is correct, but this might be easier to read. As Jorg pointed out, the use of the "self" applies to the class object, not the specific instance of it. basically mixing and matching the "self" and not-"self" entries is hard work, and you shouldn't try to cross the streams.  the "self" and non-"self" objects will act as completely different classes.

**class**

```
class ABC
  def method_1
    method_2
    p "method_1"
  end

  def self.method_3
    method_4
    p "method_3"
  end

  private

  def method_2
    p "method_2"
  end

  def self.method_4
    p "method_4"
  end
end
```

**output**

```
> ABC.new.method_1
"method_2"
"method_1"
=> "method_1"

> ABC.method_3
"method_4"
"method_3"
=> "method_3"
```

Answer (score 2):

In Ruby, the default implicit receiver of a message send, if you do not explicitly specify a receiver, is `self`.

Also, the *default definee* of a method definition expression, if you do not explicitly define a definee, is the *closest lexically enclosing module definition*.

In your first example, `method1` is defined with an explicit definee of `self`, which at that point in the execution is the class `ABC` itself. This means that `method1` is a *class method* of class `ABC`, which is actually just a *singleton method* of `ABC`, which in turn is just an *instance method* of `ABC`'s *singleton class*.

`method2` is defined *without* an explicit definee, which means it will be defined on the default definee. The closest lexically enclosing class or module definition in this case is the class definition of `ABC`, so `method2` is defined as an *instance* method of `ABC`.

In other words: `method1` and `method2` are defined in *two completely different classes*.

Now, when you call `ABC.method1`, you are sending the message `method1` to the explicit receiver `ABC`. This works, because `method1` is found in `ABC`'s singleton class.

Inside of `method1`, you are calling `method2` without an explicit receiver. That means, the message is sent to the *implicit receiver* `self`, which is `ABC` in this case. So, it is roughly equivalent (module access restrictions) to `ABC.method2`.

*BUT* there is no definition of `method2` in either the singleton class of `ABC` er the class of `ABC` (which is `Class`) or any of its superclasses (`Module`, `Object`, `Kernel`, `BasicObject`) because `method2` is defined in `ABC` itself.

Therefore, `method2` cannot be found in the method lookup chain.

In the second example, both methods are defined in the *same class*, namely both methods are defined in `ABC`'s singleton class. Therefore, `method2` is in the method lookup chain when called inside of `method1`.

In fact, your first example is actually not substantially different from this:

```ruby
class Foo
  def method 1
    method2
  end
end

class Bar
  def method2; end
end

foo = Foo.new
foo.method1
```